# How to SelectItem of ListView having GridView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I want to select **ListViewItem** on **Edit Button** click of button, present in **ListView** inside **GridView**. Using MVVM Pattern.

**Use case:** Edit option in last column in GridViewColumn, on clicking edit button, I want to hide TextBlock and show TextBox, but to do this, I want to first selectItem of ListView on Edit Button's click
In below code,
I'm having ObservableCollection List,

**User.cs** is as below

```
private string _username;
        private string _password;
        private int _age;
        private string _city;
        public string Username { get => _username; set => _username = value; }
        public string Password { get => _password; set => _password = value; }
        public int Age { get => _age; set => _age = value; }
        public string City { get => _city; set => _city = value; }

        private bool _isEdit;
        public bool IsEdit
        {
            get { return _isEdit; }
            set
            {
                _isEdit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsEdit));
            }
        }

        public User()
        {
            _username = String.Empty;
            _password = String.Empty;
            _city = String.Empty;
            _isEdit = true;
        }
        public User(string username, string password, int age, string city)
        {
            this._username = username;
            this._password = password;
            this._age = age;
            this._city = city;
            _isEdit = true;
        }
```

**View File** is as below

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
              x:Uid="Table">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="{Binding IsEdit, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">
                        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Header}"
                                        Content="Username" />
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" />
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Username}"
                                         Visibility="{Binding IsEdit, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">Age</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}"
                                         Visibility="{Binding IsEdit, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">City</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" />
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding City}"
                                         Visibility="{Binding IsEdit, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">Modify</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Edit"
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.Edit}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Path=ListViewItems}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select an item from code you need to set the Property that is bound to "SelectedItem" and then call a NotifyChange.

In your case it would be inside the Button Click-Event:

```
SelectedUser=yourItem;
NotifyChange(nameof(SelectedUser))
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to select item 'from code', selecting from XAML will also work perfectly fine. How to get access of the any ListView item (eg. yourItem) from ViewModel to change the selectedUser? From ViewModel we can't access the XAML controls ‍♂️

Comment: You cant select Items from XAML you can only Bind to a collection. What you cant do is select the item from Code. Just give your ListView a name With x:Name and cast it to a ListView. There you should have access to the SelectedItem Propertie and set the item